# Remove icons on buttons in QMessageBox

Tags: c++, qt

There is an output message with three buttons:

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question, tr(""), tr(""), QMessageBox::No | QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel, this);
messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::No, tr("1"));
messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Yes, tr("2"));
messageBox.setButtonText(QMessageBox::Cancel, tr("Cancel"));
auto response = messageBox.exec();
```

Could you tell me please how to remove the `standard icons` that are highlighted in the `red square`?

[image]

Comment: Which version of Qt are you using? I am not aware of a method called `setButtonText()`

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, version 5.15.2

Comment: okay I found the function. It is obsolete. My solution seems to work?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX, Yes, the result is, in principle, what you need. But could you tell me how to further track the pressing of these buttons. for example, earlier I did this:
`auto response = messageBox.exec();
    if (response == QMessageBox::Yes) { .... }` and `else if (response == QMessageBox::No){ ... }` in the `if` and `else` block, I specified actions when pressing a button. Now I don't understand how to specify them correctly. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot debug this right now and it is long ago since I developed in Qt. But I think the debugger could tell you which kind of response you got for each key. I think they should be the same as before. Or maybe have a look at the method `clickedButton()`. I think that is your real scenario and matches @Serhiy Kulish implementation: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#clickedButton

Comment: I found the answer to my question using the link. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try:

```
QMessageBox messageBox(this);
messageBox.addButton(tr("1"), QMessageBox::NoRole);
messageBox.addButton(tr("2"), QMessageBox::YesRole);
messageBox.addButton(tr("Cancel"), QMessageBox::RejectRole);
auto response = messageBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce it on Windows but you could try to add custom buttons to message box

```
QMessageBox messageBox(QMessageBox::Question, tr(""), tr(""), QMessageBox::NoButton, this);

QPushButton* noButton = new QPushButton(&messageBox);
noButton->setText(tr("1"));
messageBox.addButton(noButton, QMessageBox::NoRole);

QPushButton* yesButton = new QPushButton(&messageBox);
yesButton->setText(tr("2"));
messageBox.addButton(yesButton, QMessageBox::YesRole);

QPushButton* cancelButton = new QPushButton(&messageBox);
cancelButton->setText(tr("Cancel"));
messageBox.addButton(cancelButton, QMessageBox::RejectRole);

auto response = messageBox.exec();
```